# How to Determine CCD Error Line from HealthKit CDADocumentSampleWithData:'s validationError

Tags: healthkit, ccd, cda

Am trying to store a [Clinical Document Architecture (CDA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_Document_Architecture) [Continuity of Care Document (CCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_of_Care_Document) into HealthKit to display under HK's Health Records sub-section.

HealthKit's [`CDADocumentSampleWithData:startDate:endDate:metadata:validationError:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcdadocumentsample/1779395-cdadocumentsamplewithdata?language=objc) gives me:

Error code 3

and `userInfo` shows:

```
[0]
Key: NSLocalizedDescription
Value: Failed to validate XML, error code 1871
[1]
Key: HKDetailedCDAValidationErrorKey
Value: Element '{urn:hl7-org:v3}reference': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {urn:hl7-org:v3}translation ).\nElement '{urn:hl7-org:v3}reference': This element is not expected. Expected is ( {urn:hl7-org:v3}translation ).\n
```

Which gives no clue as to where (in which line) the issue exists in the CDA CCD. And to make it a little more confusing the Value element shows the string twice as shown above... and no line numbers.

"`reference`" vs "`translation`" is perhaps a clue. Unfortunately the word "`reference`" is found on 422 lines in the CCD, "`translation`" found 46 on 46 lines.

I wish I could post the CCD but it contains [PHI (protected health information)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_health_information) so I cannot.

Any hints or tips appreciated!

Comment: You really feel alone when you search stackoverflow for a cocoa method   like "CDADocumentSampleWithData" and the only hit you get is your own question. :-)

Comment: I'm here to help:)

Answer (score 1):

To validate a CDA, I always use HL7 official schemas or schematrons, both if I do local validations on my desktop using XML tools like Oxygen XML or if I do it on Java. On both cases I get detailed info and location of the errors, so these is why I recommend this option.
I hope useful.

Comment: I have been looking for an app for macOS that is a decent XML validator. Xcode parses XML but does not seem to indicate where the parsing fails short of a color change in formatting. Too subtle.  Not inclined to have Java on my workstation for a number of reasons. Looking to go native. (app)

Answer (score 1):

The key turned out to be stray empty xml tags:

```
<reference \>
```

and while someone thought it was helpful to respond with:

```
Expected is ( {urn:hl7-org:v3}translation )
```

it simply was of no use.  The *HealthKit error was basically useless* and would have been clearer if it were in Klingon.

*To find the line where the problem existed*... I found a great (not pretty) online validator which had the courtesy of providing the same error and the line number:

```
lineNumber: 9709; columnNumber: 24; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'reference'. One of '{"urn:hl7-org:v3":translation}' is expected.
```

And the link to the online validator that did what HealthKit could not:

https://www.lantanagroup.com/validator/

Comment: Yeah, Lantana Consulting Group has great tools to work with CDA.

Answer (score 0):

1. Chances are you're trying to consume a wrong document type, e.g. parse HITSP CCD as HL7 CCD.
   Determine your CDA type (there're different flavours and versions). Here's a good article on how to do this - https://motorcycleguy.blogspot.com/2017/01/what-version-of-ccda-document-is-this.html
2. Validate the CDA document. Make sure that `reference` element is where it is not by mistake. Use any of these services:

   - https://cda-validation.nist.gov/cda-validation/
   - https://www.lantanagroup.com/validator/
   - https://gazelle.ihe.net/EVSClient/cda/validator.seam?extension=IHE

Comment: Actually no, it was poor XML formatting from the source but to quench your curiosity, the clinical document statement: `<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 CDA.xsd">`